# Is it important to not exceeded the capacitance of 2.2 µF for the internal regulator of an STM32F722xx MCU?

Tags: voltage-regulator, stm32, decoupling-capacitor

[On page 109/230 of the STM32F722xx datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/dm00330506-1798964.pdf) (I use the STM32F723VE) it says that the capacitance of the external capacitor that is stabilizing the internal main voltage regulator should be 2.2 µF. We use 0603 capacitors (metric; so 0201 imperial) which are rated for 6.3 V (board is running at 3.3 V).
All the other capacitors on the board are 1.0 µF as well as 4.7 µF and in order to consolidate the BOM I was wondering whether I could replace that 2.2 µF with 4.7 µF. (In the comments someone suggested using two 1.0 µF capacitors instead of one 4.7 µF capacitor, which is a good idea.)
I have a voltage regulator for the 5V of USB on the board as well, and for that regulator I use the 1.0 µF that the datasheet calls for, in order to not mess with USB:

> The final thing is USB specs though. It only allows for 10uF at the
> device input to limit surge current. Using a 10uF at the input and
> another 10uF at the output of the regulator could easily exceed
> allowable USB ratings. Also the high capacitance at the USB inlet port
> can cause significant voltage spikes and ringing when cable is plugged
> in unless dampening is taken care of, so be careful about the design.

Can I use 4.7 µF instead of 2.2 µF for the internal regulator of the STM32F722xx series or is that a bad idea?

Comment: Might make it unstable.

Comment: Chances are your nominal "4.7uF" capacitor will be more like 2.2uF under bias. Maybe less. Usually a moderate amount higher is no problem, but I would not go an order an order of magnitude higher.

Comment: Which exact model of the F722 you are using? F7x2Rx? Have you read the hardware design guide for your MCU? If you are only using these three values, it is wrong because then you don't have the 100 nF capacitors at all?

Comment: Why don't you use two 1uF capacitors in parallel instead?

Comment: @Justme: After reading Eric Bogatins article "The Myth of Three Capacitor Values" I stopped using 100 nF capacitors when the datasheet called for something like a 100 nF and a 1 µF capacitor in parallel.

Comment: @ComprehensiveGoose OK so you are basically saying that thousands of engineers at different companies are just plain wrong and don't know what they are doing when they make hardware design guides how to use their chips?

Comment: @Justme Well, Bogatin is. He calls it legacy code. You can call it old habits die hard as well. Capacitors have changed a lot in the last 50 years, so maybe rules of thumb should change as well. ;)

Comment: @ComprehensiveGoose I'd argue that in that case the 100nF capacitor is actually more important than then 1uF. If I omitted a cap it would be the 1uF, not the 100nF, unless the 1uF is the same package size as the 100nF. At least for something like a microcontroller.

Comment: @DKNguyen Same package size: its all metric 0603 (imperial 0201). Bruce Archambeault is recomming something similar by the way: when it comes to decoupling capacitors he recommends to just go with the largest capacitance available in a certain package size (in the case of metric 0603 that is 4.7 µF; hence I use it everywhere and 100 nF nowhere).

Comment: @ComprehensiveGoose Well, the MCU manufacturer is not suggesting the old capacitor technique and it's not a high end 10Gbps system which would need more special handling than a bog standard MCU running at only about 200 MHz. If you are using a bypassing method of 10Gbps systems for a 200 MHz system, it may not make much sense. High capacitance in small package means much of the capacitance may be lost due to DC bias, even if it has low ESL.

Comment: @Justme Sadly STM is recommending the use of 100 nF capacitors in parallel with other values in the above datasheet as well. Hence I do not trust STM a whole lot when it comes to decoupling capacitors. The MCU might be only around 200 MHz, but rise times probably are small (I do not know how small though; if anyone knows, please share).

Comment: @ComprehensiveGoose Yeah, that's the conclusion I came to as well after staring at lots and lots of capacitor impedance curves. Doesn't matter most of the time though.